# ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(startrow, startcol), Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Style = "Normal" 'clear format

Tags: vba

```
arr_input = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(startrow, startcol), Cells(lastrow, lastcol))
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(startrow, startcol), Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Style = "Normal" 'clear format

'get column numbers - dynamic header
Sheets("Template").Select
'ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(headerrow, startcol), Cells(headerrow, lastcol)).AutoFilter 'remove filter if there is any
'On Error GoTo header_cannotfount
Rows(headerrow).Select
        With Selection ' dynamic header
            col_cID = .Find(What:="ps_category_list_id", After:=Range(Cells(headerrow, startcol), Cells(headerrow, startcol)), LookIn:=xlValues).Column
            col_pname = .Find(What:="ps_product_name", After:=Range(Cells(headerrow, startcol), Cells(headerrow, startcol)), LookIn:=xlValues).Column
            col_pDes = .Find(What:="ps_product_description", After:=Range(Cells(headerrow, startcol), Cells(headerrow, startcol)), LookIn:=xlValues).Column
            col_pPrice = .Find(What:="ps_price", After:=Range(Cells(headerrow, startcol), Cells(headerrow, startcol)), LookIn:=xlValues).Column
            col_pStock = .Find(What:="ps_stock", After:=Range(Cells(headerrow, startcol), Cells(headerrow, startcol)), LookIn:=xlValues).Column
            col_Weight = .Find(What:="ps_product_weight", After:=Range(Cells(headerrow, startcol), Cells(headerrow, startcol)), LookIn:=xlValues).Column
            ' col_Size = .Find(What:="ps_product_size", After:=Range(Cells(headerrow, startcol), Cells(headerrow, startcol)), LookIn:=xlValues).Column
            col_shipout = .Find(What:="ps_days_to_ship", After:=Range(Cells(headerrow, startcol), Cells(headerrow, startcol)), LookIn:=xlValues).Column
            'col_Image = .Find(What:="ps_img_id", After:=Range(Cells(headerrow, startcol), Cells(headerrow, startcol)), LookIn:=xlValues).Column
            ' col_skuref = .Find(What:="ps_sku_ref_no", After:=Range(Cells(headerrow, startcol), Cells(headerrow, startcol)), LookIn:=xlValues).Column
            col_parentsku = .Find(What:="ps_sku_ref_no_parent", After:=Range(Cells(headerrow, startcol), Cells(headerrow, startcol)), LookIn:=xlValues).Column
'            For img_i = 1 To 9
'              col_img(img_i) = .Find(What:="ps_img_" & img_i, After:=Range(Cells(headerrow, startcol), Cells(headerrow, startcol)), LookIn:=xlValues).Column
'              Next img_i
        End With

On Error GoTo unidentifiederrors:

For i = 1 To (lastrow - startrow + 1)

'ignore blank rows
 If Application.CountA(Cells(i + startrow - 1, 1).EntireRow) = 0 Then
    GoTo blankrowend
 End If
```

Comment: Run-time error '1004':  --->>> ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(startrow, startcol), Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Style = "Normal" 'clear format

Comment: which line ? try a minimal effort if you want people on this site to assist you

Comment: Why post all this code if the error occurs at the first line? and What is the error's message?

Comment: Run-time error '1004': "Normal" 'clear format

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here, please add more information and properly format your code blocks